# Why does SteamVR forget about my OpenVR dashboard app?

Tags: openvr, steamvr

I set my application to auto-launch which does not throw any error and I can see my app in SteamVR:

```cpp
auto apperror = vr::VRApplications()->SetApplicationAutoLaunch(applicationKey.c_str(), true);
if (apperror != vr::VRApplicationError_None) {
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Could not set auto start: ") + std::string(vr::VRApplications()->GetApplicationsErrorNameFromEnum(apperror)));
}
```

[image]

However if I restart SteamVR it seems to "forget" about my app and it is no longer listed.

This is my VR manifest:

```
{
    "source" : "builtin",
    "applications": [{
        "app_key": "vrphotobuddy",
        "launch_type": "binary",
        "binary_path_windows": "vrphotobuddy-overlay.exe",
        "is_dashboard_overlay": true,

        "strings": {
            "en_us": {
                "name": "VR Photo Buddy",
                "description": "VR Photo Buddy companion desktop app."
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Why does SteamVR forget about my app?

Comment: How does OpenVR find your application?

Comment: Asking that because SteamVR forgets about drivers if they are not registered properly

Comment: Also did you check the developer console?